# Type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple or Type error: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have checked similar questions and attempted various techniques and nothing works. I have included two versions of my code. I need to calculate and store the total mark for each student by going through each row in the array Student Mark but it won't run due to a type error "*TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple*"

I originally thought it was the commas, which have been the cause of most of the solutions I checked, I have double-checked these all. I then read about the range problem and attempted to address this in version 2, still no luck!

If you can help that would be very beneficial, I am new with this but can normally at least debug it...now I'm stuck though.

Version 1:

```
SubjectNo = 5

StudentName = ["Bob", "Jimmy", "Michael", "Jennifer", "Linda", "Stella", "Steven", "Lisa", "Sarah", "Jessica"]
StudentMark = [
                [76, 38, 80, 54, 55, 69, 91, 100, 64, 71, 49],
                [90, 44, 99, 19, 78, 36, 51, 53, 72, 86, 43],
                [48, 79, 59, 40, 49, 88, 46, 92, 50, 21, 36],
                [86, 54, 38, 63, 52, 82, 67, 44, 100, 98, 60],
                [66, 88, 79, 70, 22, 62, 33, 88, 91, 75, 43]
]
TotalMark = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
AvergaeMark = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
GradeAwarded = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]

for i in range(0,ClassSize):
    for m in range(0,SubjectNo):
        TotalMark[i] = TotalMark[i] + StudentMark[i,m]

for i in range(0,9):
    AverageMark[i] = TotalMark[i]/10

for i in range(0,9):
    if AvergaeMark[i] >= 70:
        GradeAwarded[i]= "distinction"
    if AverageMark[i] >=55 and AverageMark[i]< 70:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "merit"
    if AverageMark[i] >=40 and AverageMark[i]<55:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "pass"
    if AverageMark[i] < 40:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "fail"

for i in range(0,9):
    print(StudentName[i], TotalMark[i], AverageMark[i], GradeAwarded[I])
```

Version 2:

```
ClassSize, SubjectNo  = (10, 5)

StudentName = ["Bob", "Jimmy", "Michael", "Jennifer", "Linda", "Stella", "Steven", "Lisa", "Sarah", "Jessica"]
StudentMark = [
                [76, 38, 80, 54, 55, 69, 91, 100, 64, 71, 49],
                [90, 44, 99, 19, 78, 36, 51, 53, 72, 86, 43],
                [48, 79, 59, 40, 49, 88, 46, 92, 50, 21, 36],
                [86, 54, 38, 63, 52, 82, 67, 44, 100, 98, 60],
                [66, 88, 79, 70, 22, 62, 33, 88, 91, 75, 43]
]
TotalMark = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
AvergaeMark = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
GradeAwarded = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]

for i in range(ClassSize):
    for row in StudentMark:
        TotalMark[i] += TotalMark[i] + StudentMark[i, row]

for i in range(0,9):
    AverageMark[i] = TotalMark[i]/10

for i in range(0,9):
    if AvergaeMark[i] >= 70:
        GradeAwarded[i]= "distinction"
    if AverageMark[i] >=55 and AverageMark[i]< 70:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "merit"
    if AverageMark[i] >=40 and AverageMark[i]<55:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "pass"
    if AverageMark[i] < 40:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "fail"

for i in range(0,9):
    print(StudentName[i], TotalMark[i], AverageMark[i], GradeAwarded[i])
```

Neither work and create the same issue.

Comment: `StudentMark[i,m]` in python there's no 2d array. you need something like `StudentMark[i][m]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ClassSize, SubjectNo  = (10, 5)

StudentName = ["Bob", "Jimmy", "Michael", "Jennifer", "Linda", "Stella", "Steven", "Lisa", "Sarah", "Jessica"]
StudentMark = [
                [76, 38, 80, 54, 55, 69, 91, 100, 64, 71, 49],
                [90, 44, 99, 19, 78, 36, 51, 53, 72, 86, 43],
                [48, 79, 59, 40, 49, 88, 46, 92, 50, 21, 36],
                [86, 54, 38, 63, 52, 82, 67, 44, 100, 98, 60],
                [66, 88, 79, 70, 22, 62, 33, 88, 91, 75, 43]
]
TotalMark = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
AverageMark = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
GradeAwarded = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]

for i in range(SubjectNo):
    for row in range(len(StudentMark)):
        TotalMark[i] += TotalMark[i] + StudentMark[i][row]

for i in range(0,10):
    AverageMark[i] = TotalMark[i]/10

for i in range(0,10):
    if AverageMark[i] >= 70:
        GradeAwarded[i]= "distinction"
    if AverageMark[i] >=55 and AverageMark[i]< 70:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "merit"
    if AverageMark[i] >=40 and AverageMark[i]<55:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "pass"
    if AverageMark[i] < 40:
        GradeAwarded[i] = "fail"

for i in range(0,10):
    print(StudentName[i], TotalMark[i], AverageMark[i], GradeAwarded[i])
```

Output:

```
Bob 2003 200.3 distinction
Jimmy 2304 230.4 distinction
Michael 1765 176.5 distinction
Jennifer 2138 213.8 distinction
Linda 2238 223.8 distinction
Stella 0 0.0 fail
Steven 0 0.0 fail
Lisa 0 0.0 fail
Sarah 0 0.0 fail
Jessica 0 0.0 fail
```

There are a several reasons why your code did not work. First, it does not work in python to call a list like `list[someint, otherint]`. In your case that was `StudentMark[i, row]` which should be `StudentMark[i][row]`. Second your `ClassSize` is `10` but it should be `5` as there are only five items in the `StudentMark`. Also, you had `AvergaeMark` instead of `AverageMark` but you used both of them in the program so I just switched it to `AverageMark`